# HTML5 nested data-* attributes parsed with Javascript don't return a nested object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute, html-dataset

I am stuck in a concept of html5 data attributes. That attributes allows nesting like:

```
<div data-user--name="John" data-user--surname="Doe"></div>
```

I have seen plugins in the past (like [select2](https://github.com/select2/)) and some of them use the following similar syntax to make an AJAX call:

```
<div data-ajax--url="my/url" data-ajax--method="POST">
```

This code in background converts to a dataset in javascript and it returns something like this:

```
data = { 
    ajax: { 
        url: "my/url", 
        method: "POST"
    }
}
```

But in the practice, vanilla javascript's `dataset` and jQuery `data()` methods return different object content.

### Javascript

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];
el.innerHTML = "<pre>"+JSON.stringify(el.dataset)+"</pre>";
```

```html
<div data-ajax--url="my/url" data-ajax--method="POST"></div>
```

### jQuery 1.x

```js
$('div').html("<pre>"+JSON.stringify($('div').data())+"</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-ajax--url="my/url" data-ajax--method="POST"></div>
```

### jQuery 2.x

```js
$('div').html("<pre>"+JSON.stringify($('div').data())+"</pre>");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-ajax--url="my/url" data-ajax--method="POST"></div>
```

---

The code in error seems to be the jQuery 1.x versions, because in 2.x versions jQuery returns the same as vanilla Javascript. I found a related bug so it's confirmed: https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/2969

But I can't find where to construct a nested javascript object with the nested html syntax, like the following example:

```
{ 
    ajax: { 
       url: "my/url"
       method: "POST"
    }
}
```

Is there any Javascript method, or a polyfill, that makes this kind of objects reading the `data-*` HTML attributes? Is it possible to parse the data javascript strings (i.e. `ajax-Method`) and return a nested object (`ajax.method`) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into exact same need, but @artofcode's answer parses only 2 levels. So I had to figure out how to parse unlimited number of levels. Here's my solution without limiting levels, based on original answer.

```
function parseNestedDataSet(data_set) {
    var keys = Object.keys(data_set);
    var data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        var value = data_set[key];
        var splat = key.split('-');

        data = parseNestedDataSetKey(splat, value, data);
    }

    return data;
}

function parseNestedDataSetKey(keys, value, data) {
    data = data || {};
    var key = keys[0].toLowerCase();

    // Not tested, but should convert to camel case
    // var key = keys[0].replace(/-([a-z])/g, function (g) {
    //      return g[1].toUpperCase();
    // });

    if (!data[key]) {
        data[key] = {};
    }

    if (keys.length > 1) {
        keys.splice(0, 1);
        data[key] = parseNestedDataSetKey(keys, value, data[key]);
    } else {
        data[key] = value;
    }

    return data;
}
```

Didn't test it thoroughly, but it works in my case, like:

- `data-buttons--btn1--title`;
- `data-buttons--btn1--icon`;
- `data-buttons--btn2--title`.

Comment: That's great! Thank you.

Comment: Good answer, but `var key = keys[0].toLowerCase();` needs to be replaced by the result of a camel case conversion function like LoDash's `camelCase`.

Comment: Didn't need that and didn't think of that :) But You're probably right, because, I believe, jQuery also does it. Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
function parseDataset(dataset) {
    data = {};
    for(var i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataset).length; i++) {
        var key = Object.keys(dataset)[i];
        var value = dataset[key];
        var splat = key.split("-");
        console.log(key, data, splat);
        if(!data[splat[0]]) {
            data[splat[0]] = {};
        }
        data[splat[0]][splat[1]] = value;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Untested, but should work. Pass `el.dataset` into the method, get a `data` object out like:

```
data = {
    'ajax': {
        'Method': 'POST',
        'Url': 'my/url'
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't understand why but this code always returns `"123"` string: https://jsfiddle.net/nxo6nm40/

Comment: I achieve that returns an object, but is still wrong. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxo6nm40/1/

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude It's designed for objects wirth attributes, not the type of data you're giving it. Assigning a property, and then assigning properties to that property, won't work.

Comment: The type of data I'm giving it is a `dataset`, so I can't understand your point.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude You're giving it `data-object` as well as `data-object--property`. You can't assign the plain object, only its properties.

Comment: Oh, I catch you idea now. However, your code doesn't work with two properties without object: https://jsfiddle.net/nxo6nm40/2/ This returns `"123"` too.